# Предложение, в котором нужно поставить запятую

Tags: пунктуация

1. Ночь приближалась и росла как грозовая туча.
2. Он летел как стрела.
3. Пруд словно зеркало.
4. Гагарин вошёл в историю как первый космонавт.

Comment: Домашние задание напоминает...
А Вы хотя бы уверены, что такое предложение только одно из перечисленных? :)

Comment: Уверенности у меня в том нет ))) но это не домашнее задание, готовлюсь к вступительным испытаниям в вуз...

Comment: Хорошо, тогда попробую ответить на сврй страх и риск. Удачи в поступлении. 
Если не секрет, где это в середине августа еще не закрыли приемную кампанию?

Comment: Город Омск ))), благодарю за пожелание!

Comment: Ха! Пламенный привет ОЗТМ, ОНПЗ и всему лузинскому свинству.

Comment: Вы из Омска ?

Comment: Нет, это меня что-то "на слезу пробило".
Я москвич "от и до", но, наверное ни в одном другом городе не бывал столь же часто. Как-то ночью пошел из гостицы "Маяк" купаться на ближайший пляж. Когда вернулся, оправдывался, что ночью ледохода не видно. Дело было числа 14 апреля. 

Эти комменты потом удалю, флуд ведь жесточайший.

Comment: И как водичка в Иртыше по весне ? )))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Согласна: 1.Ночь приближалась и росла, как грозовая туча.-сравнительный оборот.

Он летел как стрела.- нет запятой, потому что оборот можно заменить наречием ( он летел быстро) или творительным падежом сущ.( Он летел СТРЕЛОЙ).То же самое в след.примерах: Как град (градом) посыпалась картечь. Как дым (дымом) рассеялись мечты.

С остальными объяснениями согласна.

Comment: >оборот можно заменить наречием ( он летел быстро)   
  
Да нет же. Это смотря кто этот "он". А если это вообще не о скорости?

Comment: "Лететь как стрела" Розенталь называет устойчивым выражением и приводит его в большом списке подобных фраз, где запятая не ставится, хотя можно, думаю, объяснить и возможностью заменить творительным падежом (лететь стрелой)

Comment: Это действительно классический пример во всех справочниках и учебниках.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна только в первом предложении, так как "как грозовая туча" - это явный сравнительный оборот, где "как" в значении "подобно". Лететь как стрела - это фразеологизм, запятая не нужна.Пруд словно зеркало - это сказуемое (словно зеркало), запятая не нужна. "Как первый космонавт" - здесь как в значении "в качестве" - запятая не нужна

Comment: Виктор1799, а с чего Вы взяли, что это именно фразеологизм?
А "как туча" - нет?

Comment: На фразеологизм "лететь как стрела",может, и не тянет, но Розенталь называет это устойчивым выражением и даже приводит именно его в большом списке подобных фраз, где запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что в первом и во втором предложении нужна запятая перед "как" поскольку в обоих случаях идет сравнение. Однако, поскольку во втором случае не совсем ясно, кто это "он", теоретически можно допустить, что это некий снаряд, который и летит ***в качестве*** стрелы. За уши притянуто, но формально возможно. *Ночь* же никогда *грозовой тучей* в прямом смысле быть не может. Поэтому самый правдоподобный вариант ответа - 1). Хотя и его тоже можно трактовать двояко, в т.ч. - и как часть составного сказуемого, тогда запятая не требуется. Так что однозначного ответа у меня нет. 
(Тут @Людмила нужна, она ближе к школьным делам).

Третий случай не требует запятой, поскольку здесь "словно зеркало" выступает в качестве сказуемого. Будь фраза подлиннее (типа "Пруд, словно зеркало, блистал вдалеке") обособление скорее всего бы потребовалось.

Четвертый случай очевиден. Гагарин и ***был*** первым космонавтом, а не сравнивается с ним, запятая не требуется.

Подробнее - здесь.
[ПРАВИЛА РУССКОЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ И ПУНКТУАЦИИ (1956) | gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=zap&text=19_30)